# Unexpected end of file or stream while running apt

Tags: apt

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 301729 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7_2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2) over (2.7.6-8) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive/var/cache/apt/archives/libpython2.7_2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):     cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-    gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpython2.7_2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The above is the result of `apt-get upgrade -f dpkg`. I appreciate any help you can give on this issue!

**Edit:**

Here are a few more details. I am using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 640bit. Many programs seem to be crashing and Synaptic says that `python2.7` and `libpython2.7` are broken, but is unable to fix them. Every attempt to fix them has resulted in

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1).
```

I ran `apt-get update` and then `apt-get upgrade -f dpkg` and got the result above.

Comment: What is your distro version? Have you run `apt-get update` before `upgrade`?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: do some apt-get clean first。

Answer (score 3):

Running `sudo apt-get clean` on the command line worked for me.

From a related question on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894736/what-is-sudo-apt-get-clean):

> `sudo apt-get clean` clears out the local repository of retrieved package files.

So it seems that some downloaded package file was faulty. Deleting it and applying updates (downloading the file again) fixed it.

[I would have upvoted the comment above, but lack reputation]

Comment: This answer worked in my case. Same problem, same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your Hypervisor: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2441506